# Resolve a list in Django queryset value_list

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm doing a CSV export of a queryset. For this I dynamically receive the fields by a form and I pass them to the queryset through the filter values_list directly as a list but it launches

```
AttributeError -> 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to unpack list before pass it to `values_list` with * syntax:

```
my_list = ["id", "name"]
MyModel.objects.values_list(*my_list)
```